# How to retrieve text value from RichText in flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, appium

Here's the Flutter code:

```
   Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: LuminaSpacing.extraTiny),
                  child: RichText(
                    key: Key('last_updated'),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text: '${_localize.last_updated}: ',
                      style: wldTheme.textTheme.display1,
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                            text: '${settingStore.lastCheckinTime}',
                            style: wldTheme.textTheme.body1),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I'm using appium with java to automate my test cases

Here's my code:

```
FlutterFinder ele = new FlutterFinder(driver);

System.out.println("Last update: "+ele.byValueKey("last_update"));
// System.out.println("Last update: "+ele.byValueKey("last_update").getText());  // It waits for long duration
```

The output I get is

```
Last update: [pro.truongsinh.appium_flutter.finder.FlutterElement@870fb657 -> unknown locator]
```

Comment: Please check, you are specifying `Key` and expecting element by `ValueKey`. Try passing `ValueKey<String>('last_updated')` instead of `Key('last_updated')`.

Comment: already tried that way too but didn't work. Also tried using semantic label too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a controller like this: `var textController = TextEditingController();` and aggregate the controller to your RichText widget, with this controller you can get the value of the text like this: `textController.text`

Comment: controller is not defined for RichText.